# loading to a xib from plist using grouped tableview

Tags: objective-c, plist, tableview

I am a newbie working on an app which has a grouped table view that is populated from a plist. Each cell has an image, title, and description.  All that works fine.  I also have a controller key in the plist that loads a view controller and xib.  Right now a different view controller is loaded for each cell that is selected.  However it would be nice to load the same view controller and xib but just populate the variables (an image, a text, and a sound file) from the same plist.  Can someone help me do this.  this is my code

```
//  RootViewController.h
//  TableViewPush
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface RootViewController :  UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>  {

    NSArray *tableDataSm;

}
- (IBAction)howToUse: (id) sender;  

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *tableDataSm;


@end




//  RootViewController.m
//  TableViewPush
//

#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "Location One.h"
#import "HowToUseViewController.h"
#import "TableViewPushAppDelegate.h"


@implementation RootViewController 

@synthesize tableDataSm;


- (IBAction)howToUse: (id) sender;  
{
    HowToUseViewController *how = [[HowToUseViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HowToUse"  bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:how animated:YES];
    [how release];
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TableDataSm" ofType:@"plist"];
    self.tableDataSm = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];


    self.title = @"Studios";
}
/*
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
 */
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    const NSDictionary *const sectionData = [self.tableDataSm objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionData objectForKey:@"header"];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.tableDataSm count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    const NSDictionary *const data = [self.tableDataSm objectAtIndex:section];
    const NSArray *const rows = [data objectForKey:@"rows"];
    return [rows count];
}
- (NSDictionary *)rowForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    const NSDictionary *const data = [self.tableDataSm objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    const NSArray *const rows = [data objectForKey:@"rows"];
    return [rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    const NSDictionary *const row = [self rowForIndexPath:indexPath];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [row objectForKey:@"text"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [row objectForKey:@"detailText"];
    // This assume the image file you specify exists in your bundle of course!
    NSString *imageFileName = [row objectForKey:@"image"];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageFileName];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    const NSDictionary *const row = [self rowForIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *wantedClassName = [row objectForKey:@"controller"];

    UIViewController *const vc = [[NSClassFromString (wantedClassName) alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"controller is -%@-", wantedClassName);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

    [vc release];  

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {

    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}
- (void)dealloc {

    [super dealloc];
}


@end



//  Location One.h
//  TableViewPush
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import  <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>


@interface   Location_One: UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>  {


    AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
}   

-(IBAction)pushButton;


-(IBAction)play;
-(IBAction)stop;
-(IBAction)pause;


@end





//  Location One.m
//  TableViewPush
//

#import "Location One.h"
#import "TableViewPushAppDelegate.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>

@implementation Location_One



-(id) init{
    if((self = [super initWithNibName:@"Location One" bundle:nil])){

    }
    return self;
}


-(IBAction)pushButton  {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AudioOne" ofType:@"mp3"];
    if (theAudio)[theAudio release];
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
}



-(IBAction)play {
    [theAudio play];
}
-(IBAction)stop {
    [theAudio stop];
}
-(IBAction)pause {
    [theAudio pause];
}

-(void)beginInterruption{
    [theAudio pause];

}

-(void)endInterruptionWithFlags{
    [theAudio play];
}




- (void)viewDidLoad {


    NSLog(@"InView did load");


    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Glass Illusions Studio";
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {

    [theAudio release];

    [Location_One release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
     <dict>
          <key>header</key>
          <string>85710</string>
          <key>rows</key>
          <array>
               <dict>
                    <key>text</key>
                    <string>52 Glass Illusions Studio</string>
                    <key>detailText</key>
                    <string>150 S Camino Seco, #119</string>
                    <key>image</key>
                    <string>VisualFEight.png</string>
                    <key>controller</key>
                    <string>Location_One</string>
                    <key>picture</key>
                    <string>VisualOne.png</string>
                    <key>audio</key>
                    <string>AudioOne.mp3</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>TextOne</string>
               </dict>
               <dict>
                    <key>text</key>
                    <string>53 Illusions Gallery</string>
                    <key>detailText</key>
                    <string>150 S Camino Seco, #150</string>
                    <key>image</key>
                    <string>VisualFTen.png</string>
                    <key>controller</key>
                    <string>Location_One</string>
                     <key>picture</key>
                    <string>VisualTwo.png</string>
                    <key>audio</key>
                    <string>AudioTwo.mpg</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>TextTwo</string>
               </dict>
               <dict>
                    <key>text</key>
                    <string>54 Adam Noman Metal Sculpture</string>
                    <key>detailText</key>
                    <string>7208 E Paseo San Andres</string>
                    <key>image</key>
                    <string>VisualFEleven.png</string>
                    <key>controller</key>
                    <string>Location_One</string>
                     <key>picture</key>
                    <string>VisualThree.png</string>
                    <key>audio</key>
                    <string>AudioThree.mp3</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>TextThree</string>
               </dict>
               <dict>
                    <key>text</key>
                    <string>54 Firefly Glass Gallery</string>
                    <key>detailText</key>
                    <string>8002 E Broadway Blvd</string>
                    <key>image</key>
                    <string>VisualFSeven.png</string>
                    <key>controller</key>
                    <string>Location_One</string>
                     <key>picture</key>
                    <string>VisualFour.png</string>
                    <key>audio</key>
                    <string>AudioFour.mp3</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>TextFour</string>
               </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>text</key>
                    <string>55 Red Door Studio</string>
                    <key>detailText</key>
                    <string>6323 E Printer Udell St.</string>
                    <key>image</key>
                    <string>VisualFFourteen.png</string>
                    <key>controller</key>
                    <string>Location_One</string>
                     <key>picture</key>
                    <string>VisualFive.png</string>
                    <key>audio</key>
                    <string>AudioFive.mp3</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>TextFive</string>
               </dict>
          </array>
     </dict>
     <dict>
          <key>header</key>
          <string>85711</string>
          <key>rows</key>
          <array>
               <dict>
                    <key>text</key>
                    <string>56 Fuente Y Claro</string>
                    <key>detailText</key>
                    <string>4001 E Montecito St.</string>
                    <key>image</key>
                    <string>VisualFFifteen.png</string>
                    <key>controller</key>
                    <string>Location_One</string>
                     <key>picture</key>
                    <string>VisualSix.png</string>
                    <key>audio</key>
                    <string>AudioSix.mp3</string>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>TextSix</string>
               </dict>
          </array>
     </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation of a data-driven pattern for various VCs to be loaded when different cells are selected. I showed and implementation of LocationOne, and this can be used as either a template or a Super Class for new Location VCs. I recommend you take a close look at using properties for memory management of data members (like I did in LocationOne). It really makes memory management a breeze.

RootViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDictionary *const row = [self rowForIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *wantedClassName = [row objectForKey:@"controller"];

    UIViewController *const vc = [[[NSClassFromString (wantedClassName) alloc] autorelease]


    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[Location_One class]])
    {
        Location_One* loVC = (Location_One*)vc;
        loVC.myImage = [row objectForKey:@"picture"];
        loVC.myText = [row objectForKey:@"decription"];
        loVC.mySoundFile = [row objectForKey:@"audio"];
    }

    NSAssert(vc, @"viewController should exist!");

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

    // There's no need to release the new VC because it is autoreleased 
}


// LocationOne.h
//

@interface   Location_One: UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>  
{
    AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
    NSString* myImage;
    NSString* myText;
    NSString* myAudio;
}   

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer* theAudio;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* myImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* myText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* myAudio;

-(IBAction)pushButton;
-(IBAction)play;
-(IBAction)stop;
-(IBAction)pause;
@end


// LocationOne.m
//

#import "Location One.h"
#import "TableViewPushAppDelegate.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>

@implementation Location_One

@synthesize theAudio;
@synthesize myImage;
@synthesize myText;
@synthesize myAudio;

-(IBAction)pushButton:(id)sender
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:myAudio ofType:@"mp3"];

    // theAudio is a property, therefore you can assigning it to self. will bump the retain count.
    // and decrement  the retain count for any previous audio players (releasing them).

    // Since an audio player can only set the URL at creation time, the create a new instance.
    // Using properties rather than just class members allows you to handle memory without explicit retains/releases
    self.theAudio = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL] autorelease];
    self.theAudio.delegate = self;

}

-(IBAction)play {
    [theAudio play];
}

-(IBAction)stop {
    [theAudio stop];
}

-(IBAction)pause {
    [theAudio pause];
}

-(void)beginInterruption{
    [theAudio pause];    
}

-(void)endInterruptionWithFlags{
    [theAudio play];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Glass Illusions Studio";
}

- (void)viewDidUnload 
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Only release theAudio when the view gets an unload message.
    // This is because it's recreated as needed.
    self.theAudio = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    // I'm not sure why you were doing a self-retain or self-release but I 
    // suggest against it. Let the NavigationController handle the lifetime
    // of this object.
    // [Location_One release];

    self.theAudio = nil;
    self.myImage = nil;
    self.myText = nil;
    self.myAudio = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

// This method is an older way of iOS handling memory shortages.
// You don't need it as long as you implement viewDidUnload.
// - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 

@end
```

Comment: I don't think that I made myself clear.  The view controller Location One has a xib Location One.  It has a image view, a text view, and a sound file to be played.  These change in the plist depending on the cell selected.  What I would like to do is have the same view controller and xib loaded but have the image view, text view, and sound file change to reflex what is in the plist as description, picture, and audio.  Can this be done and if so how.  I have been looking everywhere and asking all over without much success.  Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: Ok, I think I understood your original question, but let me ask you this:

Comment: Yes, I think I understood your original question, but let me ask you this: when you say "same view controller" do you mean the same instance or the same class? I believe you mean same class which is a simple UIViewController that has a UITextView, UIImageView and audio... and this is all you want/need. You just need these values to vary whenever a cell is selected. If this is the case, then I would just always open Location_One* vc = [[[LocationOne alloc] initWithValues:(x, y, z)] autorelease]; and push this onto the navigation controller? Is this clear?

Comment: Yes and no,  I see what you mean.  Yes but no in that I do not understand how to initWithValues:(x,y,z).  Could you give me and example or point me to a tutorial that would show me how to do this?  This is very helpful.  Are the variable pulled from the plist or where?

Comment: Can you tell me why your pList contains a ViewController (Location_One)? I'm trying to understand your big picture.

Comment: Yes, when a cell is selected then the view controller is loaded form the plist.  This is because there will be times when I want to load a view that is not the view with the image, text, and sound variables but another tableview.  So this is the way I was told would be the best way to do it, since before that I was using the if/else system which can get rather bulky.  This is just a trial app, The end one will have many locations within some different areas and then the locations will have either the variables or another tableview that link to a view controller with the variables.

Comment: Ok, so even though you're currently only using one VC (Location_one) you need this to be "data driven" to show different VCs depending on the cell type. But in your original question you say that a different VC is loaded for each cell selected. I suggest doing this, creating a new VC for every selected cell, and make the VC configurable (for your different params). I'll edit my above answer to show you.

Comment: Yes most of the time when a cell is selected I want to load Location One which has a xib with a image view(picture), text view(description), and audio(audio).  these variable will change depending on the cell selected.  Once in a while though when a cell is selected I want to have a different view of another tableview.  The way it is set up now I can have different view controller for each cell selected each with its own xib.  Which is ok,  I just thought It would be a bit cumbersome to have over 200 view controllers and xibs.  But if that is the way it has to be ok.

Comment: If you see the edited answer above, you can see that LocationOne is design to vary depending on the parameters. did it make sense?

Comment: Yes, except this place in the code that gives me an error property 'text, image, soundFile' not found on object of type "Location_One"

Comment: I get an error that 'Property 'text, image, soundFile' not found on object type 'Location_One''  If I change them to myImage, myText, myAudio there is no error but the app crashes before loVC.myImage = [row objectForKey:@"picture"];    any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Yes, typo... you should use the exact property names:  myImage, myText, myAudio

Comment: Ok I did that, Yet when I get to the loVC.myImage = [row objectForKey;@"picture"]; the app crashes stopped at breakpoint 1 If I Continue the program the xib is loaded but with no picture, no audio, and no text.

Comment: :) sounds like you need some debugging. At this point it's something small. Have you worked much with debuggers? Set a breakpoint in -(IBAction)pushButton:(id)sender and see what happens. You're almost there. If you need some more help, send me your email, and I'll contact you offline when I can spare some more time.

Comment: So I was wrong when you run the app without the breakpoints being checked at the top of Xcode the program launches and when you select a cell the xib is pushed to the top but there are no images, no text and no audio.  I feed these to the vc but in location one is there a method to display them?  Also when I have another vc in a cells plist controller the app crashes.  I want to be able to once in a while call a different vc like location two that would maybe have another table view.  is this possible with this configuration?  My email is benok@dakotacom.net  Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is a whole new set of questions... You have to design Location_One to use an UIImageView for your image and UITextView for text. And if you use a different VC in your plist, then you have to create the class: "Location_Two". Are you trying to learn to program or is this just a business prototype? If you're trying to learn, then I can suggest some good paths to learn. If it's business prototype, the I suggest getting some programming help. I'll email you.